# Can't import as null value SQL Server 2008 TSV file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I import data from a TSV file with SQL Server 2008.

null is replaced by 0 when I confirm a table after import　with integer column.

How to import as null, please Help me!!

Comment: What method: bcp, BULK INSERT or SSIS?

Comment: Thak you for comment . I use Import Wizard

Comment: ..which actually runs an SSIS package

Comment: Yes How to resolve it in SSIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), -k switch
- Using [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), use KEEPNULLS

After comment:

- Using SSIS "Bulk insert" task, options page, "Keep nulls" = true
  This is what the import wizard uses: but you'll have to save and edit it first because I see no option in my SSMS 2005 wizard.

Comment: how to set this value?? options tab from tools menu??

Answer (score 1):

This can be set in the OLE DB Destination editor....there is a 'Keep nulls' option.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative for those using the Import and Export Wizard on SQL Server Express, or anyone who finds themselves too lazy to modify the SSIS package:

Using text editing software before you run the wizard, replace NULLs with a valid value that you know doesn't appear in your dataset (eg. 987654; be sure to do a search first!) and then run the Import Export Wizard normally. If your data contains every single value (maybe bits or tinyints), you'll have some data massaging ahead of you, but it's still possible by using a temporary table with datatypes that can store a greater number of values. Once it's in SQL, use commands like

```
UPDATE TempTable
SET Column1 = NULL
WHERE Column1 = 987654
```

to get those NULLs where they belong. If you've used a temporary table, use INSERT INTO or MERGE to get your data into your end table.